# Ordering with repeats

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, order

A quick question on list ordering, how can I easily get the ordering of the list, so that, for

```
{0, Sqrt[3], 2 Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3], 3, 2 Sqrt[3]}
```

I get

```
{1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4}
```

`Ordering` does not seem to work.

**Edit:** Thank you for all the wonderful answers. What might be the best way to test which one is the fastest, maybe `RepeatedTiming`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list = {0, Sqrt[3], 2 Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3], 3, 2 Sqrt[3]}

list /. Union @ Flatten @
   MapIndexed[
    #1 -> #2[[1]] &,
    Split @ SortBy[N] @ list,
    {2}]
```

{1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4}

Also

```
With[{x = N @ list},
 Flatten @ Replace[x, MapIndexed[Rule] @ Union[x], {1}]]
```

{1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4}

Comment: Thanks. Can you compare it with my answer? Is this faster?

Comment: With `list = Flatten@Table[list, {100000}]` my answer is almost twice as fast

Answer (score 6):

**Using `Lookup`:**

```
list = {0, Sqrt[3], 2 Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3], 3, 2 Sqrt[3]}

a1 = DeleteDuplicates@SortBy[list, N]
rules = Thread[a1 -> Range@Length@a1]
Lookup[rules, list]
```

---

*Result:*

> {1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4}

Answer (score 6):

Just an alternative, combining `OrderingBy` with `DeleteDuplicates`

```
list = {0, Sqrt[3], 2 Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3], 3, 2 Sqrt[3]};

list /. Thread[# -> OrderingBy[#, N]]&@DeleteDuplicates@list
```

> `{1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4}`

Answer (score 5):

```
l = {0, Sqrt[3], 2  Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3], 3, 2  Sqrt[3]};
```

Using `Split`, `SortBy` and `Thread`:

```
l /.Rule @@@ Splice@*Thread /@ Thread[{#, Range@Length@#}] &@Split@SortBy[N]@l

(*{1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4}*)
```

Comment: But I want the same numbers to correspond to the same ranks. Perhaps ordering is not the word? So 0->1, Sqrt[3]->2, 3->3 and 2  Sqrt[3]-> 4

Comment: @samwolfe Your solution is still faster.

Answer (score 4):

```
rankList[list_] := 
 Replace[#, PositionIndex[Sort@DeleteDuplicates@#][[All, 1]], 1] &@
  N[list]
```

seems to do the trick, though I need to use `N`.